# If there exists a sequence $(\phi_n)$ of step functions such that $\phi_n \longrightarrow f$ almost everywhere on $[a,b]$, can we prove that $f\in L$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

I know, if $f\in L$ (the set of all Lebesgue integrable functions), then there exists a sequence $(\phi_n)$ of step functions such that $\phi_n \longrightarrow f$ almost everywhere on $[a,b]$ and $\lim\int_a^b\phi_n = \int_a^bf$. But the question is: the converse is also true? If yes, please give me a proof. If no, give me a counterexample, please.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If $f$ is any measurable function, integrable or not, there are step functions converging to $f$ almost everywhere.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Moreover, one can always have a sequence of finite step functions converging to $f$ a.e, also the convergence is uniform as long as $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I've not studied mensurable functions yet. But the information helps me a lot.

Comment: For $n\in\mathbb N\cup \{0\}$ let $f_n = 2^{n+1} \chi_{[2^{-n-1}, 2^{-n})}$ and $g_n = f_0 + \dotsb + f_n$. Is the limit of $g_n$ integrable?

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín Can you find a sequence of step functions converging uniformly to $\sin (1/x)$ on $(0,1)?$